# How to use dd to fill a disk with a specific char?

Tags: linux, dd, block-device

I know i can fill an entire disk with 0x0 like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4k conv=notrunc
```

Is there a way to fill the entire disk with a char of my choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
yes "<char>" | dd of=/dev/sda bs=4k conv=notrunc
```

Substitute  with character of your choice.

Comment: Unfortunately `yes` adds EOL character.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur To fix this: `yes "<char>" | tr -d "\n" | dd of=/dev/sda conv=notrunc`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
while true; do echo -n 'x'; done | dd of=/dev/sda bs=4k conv=notrunc iflag=fullblock
```

Comment: adding a iflag=fullblock ensures writes happen at 4k granularity.

Answer (score 2):

```
yes "" | tr "\n" "<char>" | dd of=/dev/sda <rest of dd parameters>
cat /dev/zero | tr "\0" "<char>" | dd of=/dev/sda <rest of dd parameters>
cat /dev/zero | sed "y/\0x00/<char>/" | dd of=/dev/sda <rest of dd parameters>
```

Where `<char>` is your chosen character